# How to output a Numpy array to a file object for Picloud

Tags: python, numpy, cloud

I have a matrix-factorization process that I'm running on picloud. The output is a set of numpy arrays (ndarray).

Now, I want to save it to my bucket, but I'm not able to zero in on the right way to do it. Let's assume that the array to be saved is P.

I tried:

```
cloud.bucket.putf(P,'p.csv')
```

but that returned an error: "IOError: File object is not seekable. Cannot transmit".

I tried

```
numpy.ndarray.tofile(P,f, sep=",", format="%s") #outputing the array to a file object f
cloud.bucket.putf(f,'p.csv') #saving the file object f in the bucket.
```

I tried a couple of other things, including using using numpy.savetext (as I would if I ran it locally) but I'm not able to solve this between the picloud documentation and stackexchange questions. I haven't tried pickle yet, though. I felt this was something straightforward, but I'm feeling quite silly after spending a few hours on this.

Comment: How are you opening `f` (read-write, write-only...)? You should also close and reopen it before attempting `cloud.bucket.putf`, or alternatively just use `cloud.bucket.put` with a filename.

Comment: I was actually trying to turn the array P to a file-object f, as the documentation for `cloud.bucket.put` needs a file-object as an input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, you want to pickle the array as follows:

```
import cloud
import cPickle as pickle

# to write
cloud.bucket.putf(pickle.dumps(P), 'p.csv')

# to read
obj = pickle.loads(cloud.bucket.getf('p.csv').read())
```

This is a general way to serialize and store any Python object in your PiCloud Bucket. I also recommend that you store your csv files under a prefix to keep it organized [1].

[1] http://docs.picloud.com/bucket.html#namespacing-with-prefix

Comment: Thanks! I've done this, and I think I've solved my test case. Now to run the larger exercise. Much obliged. And yes, I'll use prefixes, that's very good advice.